# Data structure for sentence completion suggestions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

If a word is typed in Google, it will show a list of words as suggestions in a drop-down list.

For example, if you type `what`, it will show `what is your name`, `what is your father's name`, `what is your college name`, etc. in 8 words.

What is a suitable data structure, as well as best way to list those suggestions?

Comment: What means "suitable" and "best way"? As long as your goals are not specified, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: If you're only dealing with prefixes: Possibly [a trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Possibly a database where you do a `LIKE '...%'` and `ORDER BY` for popular ones first.

Comment: Something [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) way?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901831/algorithm-for-autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method is to use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) where each edge is weighted according to the probability that the next letter correspond to this edge so that first suggestions have higher probabilities.