# Address bar suggestion implementation

Tags: algorithm, firefox

Can you please explain how the address bar suggestions are implemented in Firefox. This is the feature where by all history urls matching my string are shown.
I understand that they would have stored the urls in a file and probably use regex to match the strings but can i know the exact implementation.
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer explains how it is done in Firefox 3.0 - 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540725/how-does-firefoxs-awesome-bar-match-strings/1208458#1208458).  In Firefox 4.0, there is an additional step before the last query that is executed that searches pages that are open in tabs.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by exact implementation? It is as simple as do a loop for a list of string, and any string matching it is displayed? Maybe you need to clarify more about your project environment? What you are trying to achieve? Are you creating your own browser? Or you plan to create a web site that can auto suggest? Or you need algorithm help?

Too many possibilities...

Comment: I was trying to look up the implementation that firefox uses for educating myself. So it would be helpful if you could explain the implementation that firefox uses.